# Nginx Proxy not passing real ip

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, next.js, proxy

I have an Ubuntu Server 22.04 running Nginx and a nodejs server (pm2) used to host multiple websites.

One of the apps, is a NextJs front end that connects to a PHP back end API. I'm running Nginx 1.24 to handle the API and PHP requests and it has a proxy set up to the node server (pm2).

The issue I have is, when the app makes a call to the API (through `getServerSideProps`) I get the Servers external IP address, instead of the Users IP address in the NGINX access logs.

BUT this only happens on my Production server. On my test server with the same site, config, etc, I get the real users IP address logged as hitting the API in the NGINX access logs.

I don't know where else to look for discrepancies between the two server/site configs to try and locate the issue.

Any help and/or constructive criticism is appreciated.

My next.config.js:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/:path*`,
        },
        {
            source: '/public/:path*',
            destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/public/:path*`,
        },
    ]
},
```

Here is one of the NGINX server blocks proxy.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9003;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}

location /api {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```